# Determine if values from text file are unique

Tags: c++, file, validation, input

I'm in a class where we're learning C++, and our first project is to read in data from a text file, perform various checks on this data, and output it to another file in a slightly altered form.

The original data has columns separated by spaces. We are to check the first column (an ID) to ensure each row has a unique ID. We are also supposed to check the 10th column to ensure it has one of four values. I have no issue checking the 10th column, but I'm having an issue checking if the ID of each row is unique.

In Java, I would add each ID to a vector or array, and then check to see if the vector contains each subsequent element, and throw an error if it does. But, we are only allowed to include three headers in our project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
```

So, I cannot check for unique IDs using vectors or arrays. Any help on what I might do here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a string that accumulates a list of all the IDs encountered so far, separated by some character that cannot appear in an ID. Use `string::find` to check whether each new ID has already appeared before.

Comment: If you're only allowed those 3 headers, how are you reading data from a file? Or is the file being piped into stdin from the command line?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I think it is piped. Teachers do that

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of a string in c++ and store IDs in that array. then use this loop to check for duplicate elements.

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<s.length();j++)
        {
            if(s[i]==[j])
            {
                cout<< s[i] << " is duplicate";
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

something like this. This is alright for class exercise since you are learning. I do not recommend this for production.

```
class myvector{
const int maxsz = 1000;
std::string data[maxsz];
int currentsz;

void insert(); //increment size;
std::string get(int); //retrieve an index;
bool compareToAll(const std::string& val) {
    for(int i = 0; i < currentsz; ++i ) {
        if(val == data[i]) return true;
        }
    return false;
   }

};
```

Ideally I would use a set or unordered_set. vector is n^2;

Since you are learning, I would recommend trying overloading operators.